# How do I pass a class's state as props in another class?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to create a React App that fetches data based on filters given by the user. I have two classes, Filters and News. In Filters, I want to set sourceName and countryCode as state; then fetch based on these parameters in News. How do I pass the state values as props in News?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to pass the state from the parent of both elements.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Parent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            sourceName: null,
            contryCode: null
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Filters {...this.state} />
                <News {...this.state} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

You should always keep state in an element higher up in the render chain then all the children that need it.  Doing this allows you to trickle down the state to all children that need it.  Then only time state should be maintained within a component is if that component is the only component that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

you can simple pass the state down as props in the child.
like `<News filter={this.state.filer} />`.